# how to search by foreign key in algolia instant search?

Tags: algolia

Suppose, I have 5 countries and there are 10 cities in each country and then again, there are 20 different places in each city.There are 3 tables in RDBMS and the thing is I want to implement search using algolia instant search js. Can anyone please tell me, how can i achieve search like, when I search OR filter one country and search results show the places of particular country. Which tables needs to be indexed in algolia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Algolia record for each place. Inside of that document, you should include the attributes of the city and country that you'd like to search on (city.name, country.name, etc).

Comment: You mean to say that I will have only one index i.e. places and I have to insert country.name and city.name in places table while inserting data of places. Can you please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Right, you got it! In a sense, you're flattening/denormalizing your data model so that you have the full place, city and country in each record. That avoids having to do any joins and makes the process at query time very simple. For your searchableAttributes, you'll want to have name (or place.name if you nest the place object), city.name, and country.name, probably in that order.